# I want to fix the behavior of my function

Tags: r

I'm making a function that categorize the customers based on there sales  into 3 classes A,B and C, but the function give me wired results i don't know why

```
f <- function(x)
{
  for(j in 1:length(x))
  {


      if(x[j] > 0 & x[j] < 501 )
      {
        x[j] = "C"
      }

      else if(x[j] > 500 & x[j] < 1001 )
      {
        x[j] = "B"
      }

      else if(x[j] > 1000  )
      {
        x[j] = "A"
      }

  }
return(x)
  }
```

This is the function.

```
print(f(c(2000,2000,2000)))
```

when i run this for example it gave me A,C,C where is should be all A

```
print(f(c(600,600)))
```

this gave B which is right but then A !

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @shwan you were rewriting the x vector as character values. To avoid defining an other vector for result and also avoid the loop structure you could just use the vectorized `ifelse` command and write your function as:

```
f=function(x){ifelse(x>0 & x<501,"A",ifelse(x>500 & x <1001,"B","C"))}
```

Comment: Much better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

By using `x[j] = "C"`, you are coercing `x` to class 'character', which then returns unexpected logical comparisons.

You need to save the result in some other, character vector (`'ret'` below).

```
f <- function(x) {

    ret <- NA_character_
    for(j in 1:length(x)) {
        if(x[j] > 0 & x[j] < 501 )  {
            ret <- c(ret,"C")
        } else if(x[j] > 500 & x[j] < 1001 ) {
            ret <- c(ret,"B")
        } else if(x[j] > 1000  ) {
            ret <- c(ret,"A")
        }
    }
    ret <- ret[2:length(ret)] # remove the first element
    return(ret)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the demonstration